# Android development and sql database on windows 7

Tags: android, mysql, windows-7, installation

I've just started developing android applications.
Currently I have developed an app that can scan for wireless networks and list them on the screen.

My next goal is to save this data in an database. I thought that I could use my home computer runnning Win7 and install mysql. I've tried to install mysql 5.1 and 5.5 on my computer but with no success. Should I try something else or could you guys provide me with an installation guide?

I've already tried several guides, but with no luck. I always end up with "mysql server instance config wizard not responding"

Comment: So is this really an Android problem, or are you just having trouble installing MySQL on Windows?

Comment: You want to scan for wireless networks with an android application and then insert that data into a mysql database on your home pc? or are you trying to save the database information to a database located on your android device?

Comment: eldarerathis: its both. I would like info for the best solution for saving the data on a remote machine. And if its MySql i have to use, then have tried to install it, but with no luck and cant figure out why.

Comment: From your comments below, it's clear that the specific problem you are having have nothing to do with Android. Tagging it Android and mentioning it in the post is misleading and explains why Heather's and my answers were about SQLite. I suggest you start over with a new question focused on what you really need at the moment: a way to get a server-side dbms set up on your Windows machine.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [SQLite Database Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) at SourceForge. It's a nice, simple tool for manipulating SQLite data bases. If you want to write J2SE programs to access an SQLite database, download [SQLiteJDBC](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) from zentus.com.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to use SQLite, although it's another option, on Windows

Comment: @dtmilano - The question is tagged "Android" and OP says this is for Android. That means SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SQLite for android development. When I use Windows 7 to develop, I use tksqlite. It a free download with a good GUI and lots of options. Download it here: http://code.google.com/p/tksqlite/

Comment: It is possible to use a communicate with other databases such as MySQL through a webservice so Freddy is not limited to SQLite.

Comment: @Leffy - If Freddy wants to use a data base in an Android app, SQLite is the only dbms supported by Android.

Comment: Heather - the tksqlite project at the link you gave seems to be empty of content: no downloads, no source. Here's a [better link](http://reddog.s35.xrea.com/wiki/TkSQLite.html)

Comment: Thanks...should've checked the link

Comment: I want to save the data from the android app on a remote machine, in this case my home computer with win 7. I didnt thought i've had to use SqlLite.

Comment: @TedHopp Even if SQLite is the only supported dbms it does not me he is limited to SQLite. MySql can be used trough a webservice and I've done this myself in a project. A quick search containing the keywords android, mysql and php should give plenty of results.

Comment: @Leffy thats allso what thought, but i can't reinstall mysql on my win 7 machine because of forgotten "current root password". I've tried to follow this guide: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html 
but without any luck.

Comment: @freddy I am not very experienced in setting up MySQL, as I used a server that was already setup with PHP and MySQL for my project. I hope someone more experienced will be able to give you helpful advice in this aspect.